# How to Push crontab to Production Server (Nginx)

Tags: django, nginx, cron

Django Project: I have a crontab task which sends email notification to all users. Here are the set of procedures which I would like to deploy it to production server using fabfile.

```
$ sudo crontab -e
1 * * * * pathtovirtualenv/python pathto/manage.py run_notifications

$ sudo service cron restart
```

I would like to deploy the above steps to production server which sends weekly email notifications to all users. but sad thing I'm unable to test it on my working machine which is sending constant postfix/sendmail errors. I'm hoping if I could deploy it to production server which doesn't raise any issues like my working machine.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked about, but it's not difficult to set up a mail server for development/debugging:

```
python -m smtpd -c DebuggingServer -n
```

Connect to that on 8025 and it will print email to stdout. You can also run this programmatically from your test suite if you prefer: https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtpd.html

Ultimately, the answer to a testing problem is to figure out the testing, not to push to production and hope for the best. :)